# Random Sample with remove from List

Tags: python, list, random

I have data in a list like:

```
L = [(3,4,5),(1,4,5),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

I need to sample randomly a size of 2 so I wanted to use:

```
import random
t1 = random.sample(set(L),2)
```

Now T1 is a List of the randomly pulled values, But i wanted to remove those randomly pulled from our initial list from our initial list. I could do a linear for loop but for the task I'm trying to do this for  a larger list. so the Run time would take for ever!

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
t1 = [L.pop(random.randrange(len(L))) for _ in xrange(2)]
```

doesn't change the order of the remaining elements in `L`.

Comment: For those who don't know, xrange as been replaced by range in Python3.

Answer (score 13):

One option is to shufle the list and then pop the first two elements.

```
import random
L = [(3,4,5),(1,4,5),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
random.shuffle(L)
t1 = L[0:2]
```

Comment: -1 `random.shuffle` is an in-place function, and thus returns `None`. This answer gives: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: @jamylak Sorry, I have corrected the error. Thanks for the feedback